# Micronaut data Transactional Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, micronaut, micronaut-data

I have to test a pessimistic lock implementation done with Micronaut data and Hibernate. When I am running the JUnit test case,with command `gradle test` it is giving error

`io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type [org.hibernate.Session]: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread`

But the function (orgAccountRepository.findTop1ByStatus) is working as expected, when called in the context of a controller.

To make things even weird, the test run successfully when executed with vs code java test runner.

This test is to verify that the pessimistic write lock on table rows are working. So essentially I have to create multiple concurrent transactions that compete to acquire lock and then verify that the locking mechanism is working.

Can someone give any advice on defining transactions with JUnit.

```java
@Repository
public abstract class OrgAccountRepository implements CrudRepository<OrgAccount, String> {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public OrgAccountRepository(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public Optional<OrgAccount> findTop1ByStatus(OrgAccountStatusName name) {
        // Lock the result rows with PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock
        List<OrgAccount> orgAccounts = entityManager
                .createQuery("FROM OrgAccount AS oa WHERE oa.status = :status", OrgAccount.class)
                .setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE).setParameter("status", name)
                .getResultList();
        if (orgAccounts.size() > 0) {
            return Optional.ofNullable(orgAccounts.get(0));
        }

        return Optional.ofNullable(null);
    }

}
```

```java
@MicronautTest(environments = {"test"})
public class LockTableTest {
    @Inject
    LockTableHelper lockTableHelper;

    @Test
    void test() {
       Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                lockTableHelper.testRun();
            }
        };
        t1.start();

        //<Thread join and other logics>

        ....
        ....
    }

}
}
```

```java
public class LockTableHelper {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LockTableHelper.class);

    @Inject
    OrgAccountRepository orgAccountRepository;
    @Transactional
    public void testRun() {
        Optional<OrgAccount> account =
                orgAccountRepository.findTop1ByStatus(OrgAccountStatusName.UNASSIGNED);
    }
}
```

Comment: is LockTableHelper  missing a singleton or a context annotation?

Comment: I added @Context annotation in helper class. But the problem still exists.

Comment: Why are you starting a new thread in your test?  I think one problem with that approach is depending on what your CPU is doing when the test is run, the test method may complete before that thread ever even runs.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, I updated the question to explain it. Threads are to create multiple concurrent transactions, to test a locking mechanism on table.

Comment: Got it.  The code before your edit wouldn't have worked reliably.